# how to pass an integer to a function and return a string

Tags: c

I am trying to write a function (and failing badly!!) that passes an int as a parameter and returns a string which is generated from a mysql query - see below code:

I would like after I have have that working like to be able to pass a number of parameters (1 int and 2 chars) and have returned 3 strings, I guess those will require a struct and pointers but i'll start with the simple stuff.. crawl first..run later :)

Here is the code I have written I have removed the function but it's failing on compile at the line

```
retString =  strFunction(Value);
```

with the error:

```
warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

I can post the full code if required..

Many Thanks in advance.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

char *retString;
retString =  strFunction(Value);
printf("The Return string is:  %s", retString);
Exit (0);

}


char *strFunction(int Value)
{

perform code here using value;
Return retString;

}
```

Okay here's the full code.. messy I know... embarrassment got the better of me posting originally..

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int Exhibit = 1;
char *rtn_Exhibition;
rtn_Exhibition =  rtn_ex(Exhibit);
printf("The Exhibition is set to:  %s", rtn_Exhibition);
}


char *rtn_ex(int Exhibit)
{
static char selectEx[2];
unsigned int i;
char selectEx_rtn[20];
memset(selectEx, 0, sizeof(selectEx));
sprintf(selectEx, "SELECT exhibition_description FROM exhibitions WHERE exhibition_id='%d'",Exhibit);
printf("\nThe SELECT statement you have built is: %s\n", selectEx );
connectDB();
if (mysql_query (conn, selectEx) != 0)
    {
        print_error (conn, "mysql_query() failed");
    }
else
    {
    res_set = mysql_store_result (conn); /* generate result set */
    // printf("The value of  the result set is: %d\n", res_set);    
    if (res_set == NULL)
        { 
            print_error(conn, "mysql_store_result() failed");
        }
    else
        {
        //process_result_set(conn, res_set);
        MYSQL_ROW row;
        while ((row = mysql_fetch_row (res_set)) != NULL)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < mysql_num_fields (res_set); i++)
            {
                sprintf(selectEx_rtn, "The exhibition name is: %s",   (row[i]));
            }

        }
    }
    mysql_free_result(res_set);
}
disconnectDB();
return selectEx_rtn;
}
```

Hi T Thanks for your response, in answer to your comments:

1) That's correct, I didn't spot that. Yes there are 70 characters for the SELECT statement + the int that goes in the single quotes which will be a 1-9 number. I have adjusted the array as now 80 characters

2) The MYSQL_RES pointer is set earlier in the program:

MYSQL_RES *res_set;

3) I adjusted this to 30 characters but I get an error stating that selectEX_rtn warning: function returns address of local variable. I changed selectEx_rtn to a pointer and the function works but dies straight afterwards with a segmentation fault

Comment: yes please post the full code.

Comment: There are lots of problems here. (1) You don't declare `Value`. (2) You don't do anything in your function `strFunction`. (3) You didn't post your full code.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: also, I hope your code has a syntax `strFunction(Value);`, not `strFunction(int Value);`

Comment: you need prototype(`char *strFunction(int value);`) before main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have lots of errors here.

1. you declare `static char selectEx[2];` as a character array that has a width of two characters, yet later on you attempt to do: `sprintf(selectEx, "SELECT exhibition_description FROM exhibitions WHERE exhibition_id='%d'",Exhibit);`.  This will result in a buffer overflow.  For the static part of the query you need 70 characters.  Assuming that you are using 32-bit integers, you will need another 10 characters to insure that you can hold the longest it.  From this you should declare selectEX to be at least 80 characters wide.  **Suggestion**: Set the size of *selectEX* to at least 80 characters wide (and double check my counting of the number of characters needed).
2. In this line of code `res_set = mysql_store_result (conn);` you are using *res_set* without declaring it.  It is possible that the compiler is assuming that *res_set* is an int and it appears that `mysql_store_result` is returning a pointer. This might be the source of your error.  **Suggestion:** declare *res_set* correctly.
3. In this line of code `sprintf(selectEx_rtn, "The exhibition name is: %s",   (row[i]));` you have declared *selectEX* to be a twenty character wide array (`char selectEx_rtn[20];`).  Yet the static part, *i.e.* "The exhibition name is: " requires 24 characters.  Another buffer-overflow here, and that is not counting the number of characters in `row[i]`.  **Suggestion**: Change the declaration of *selectEx* to be wide enough to hold the data.  Additionally, using a width specifier with the %s, *i.e.* %15s, may help.

Hope this helps, 
T

Comment: 1) Hi T, Thanks for your response. That's correct, I didn't spot that. Yes there are 70 characters for the SELECT statement + the int that goes in the single quotes which will be a 1-9 number. I have adjusted the array as now 80 characters

2) The MYSQL_RES pointer is set earlier in the program:

MYSQL_RES *res_set;

3) I adjusted this ut I get an error stating that selectEX_rtn warning: function returns address of local variable

I changed selectEx_rtn to a pointer and the function works but dies straight afterwards with a segmentation fault.

Comment: Is `res_set` global, or declared in another function?  Also, when you are returning a pointer to selectEX_rtn, is the storage for this allocated on the stack or on the heap?  It may be useful to edit the code in your original question to reflect what you currently have (i.e. while rtn_ex now returns a pointer to a character, selectEx_rtn is still 20-characters wide.